# Cannot Deploy GCP Python Cloud Function

Tags: python, shell, google-cloud-platform, faas

I've been using GCP for some time.

I created a new `GCP` Project to test new functions, and enabled the `Runtime API`.

However, clicking Deploy pops up this message:
"User does not have the 'iam.serviceAccounts.actAs' permission on webcalc-taskc2@appspot.gserviceaccount.com required to create the function. You can fix this by running gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding webcalc-taskc2@appspot.gserviceaccount.com --member=user: --role=roles/iam.serviceAccountUser"

I entered this into `Shell`, replacing  with my Owner email for GCP. Still no luck ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add permissions that can use service account to your account.

According to [Google document](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts), A service account is a special type of Google account intended to represent a non-human user that needs to authenticate and be authorized to access data in Google APIs.

Seems that "webcalc-taskc2@appspot.gserviceaccount.com" is your service account runs cloud function.

The pop up message you received said that a user account running cloud function does not have 'iam.serviceAccounts.actAs' permission on that service account.

So you have to entered command in the message with replaced --member=user to --member=user:***Your account email***.

You can check your cloud function service account at details -> General information tab.

[image]

Comment: Ty for contributing! Can you possibly link more or tell me step by step how to add all the appropriate permissions to my service account please? I don't think I can access Details > General Information as I am yet to create a function in this project

Comment: My bad, I misunderstanding your question. Did you mean you replaced --member=user to your owner e-mail? If yes, It should have worked. Refer to https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#role-actAs to get detailed informations. I edited my answers.

Comment: I replace the gap after "member-user=" with my Owner email address

Comment: You should have to replaced "member=user:YOUR_ACCOUNT", not "member-user=YOUR_ACCOUNT" Same problem occurred after correction?